# Variable inside JSON string

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am working on an app to make CVs and I have a JSON file with job descriptions the user can choose from. The problem is that the aircraft the user flies can be many and I would like to add a variable I can change inside the JSON string. Something like this:

```
{
"data":[
  {
    "jobDescription": "Worldwide Passenger and freighter flights in all weather conditions, on the modern " + yourAirplane + ". I Have gained experience flying to destinations in all continents while working with different nationalities"
  }
 ]
}
```

I have been googling but I couldn't find anything. I parse the string with the following code:

```
struct  JobDescriptionData : Decodable{
    var data:[JobDescritpion]?
}

class JobDescritpion:  NSObject, Decodable {

    static let shared = JobDescritpion()

    var jobDescription : String?

    func loadJobDescriptions(completion: ([JobDescritpion]) -> ()){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jobDescription", ofType: "json")!
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                    data.printJSON()
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    guard let eventResult = try? decoder.decode(JobDescriptionData.self, from: data) else { return }

                    var array = [JobDescritpion]()
                    array = eventResult.data!
                    completion(array)

                    } catch {
                }
    }
}
```

`printJSON()` (which is my extension to Data to print the json array) works and it returns the array but of course, the guard let fails because `jobDescription` is not a string.

Any Advice on how I can add a variable and then set it later in the app?

Comment: Where does this variable come from? Maybe you are looking for something like the placeholders in localized strings.

Comment: The user adds his flight hours so I will be able to know what aircraft he flew. I have a an array with this aircraft so when the user chose the job description for that specific job/airplane then the variable is set. I am not sure it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the JSON as a string:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "jobDescription": "Worldwide Passenger and freighter flights in all weather conditions, on the modern <yourAirplane>. I Have gained experience flying to destinations in all continents while working with different nationalities"
    }]
}
```

After decoding:

```
"description".replacingOccurrences(of: "<yourAirplane>", with: yourAirplane)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use String Format for your JSON

example

```
let stringTemplate = "Worldwide Passenger and freighter flights in all weather conditions, on the modern %@. I Have gained experience flying to destinations in all continents while working with different nationalities"

let formattedString = String(format: stringTemplate , "some value")
print(formattedString)
```